# How can I get lucene's docId from search result?

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm implementing `FastVectorHighlighter` in my application. But It requires `docId`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a projection.

See this paragraph in the reference documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections
You even have an example of how to do it.

See especially the FullTextQuery.DOCUMENT_ID projection.

Comment: How can I map DOCUMENT_ID  to Entity property?